# Delete one project of my solution in codeplex

Tags: azure-devops, codeplex

I have a set of projects as known is VS as Solution in Codeplex.com and I want to delete one project from this solution. Is there a way to delete this particular project from all of the solution and not the entire solution project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

open source control explorer(right click on TFS *VS 2012* Select action then source explorer control) delete the selected project then checkin